# Why is single iteration for map insertion and map.find() much slower than two separate iterations for insert and for map.find()

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures

I find an interesting phenomenon when I try to optimize my solution for the leetcode two sum problem (https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/description/). 
Leetcode description for the two-sum problem is:

> Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target. 
>   You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

Initially, I solve this problem by using two loops. First I loop through input array to store array value and array index as  pair into a map. Then I loop through input array again to loop up each element and check if it exists in the map. The following is my solution from leetcode:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) 
    {
        vector<int> res;
        map<int, int> store;

        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i)
        {
            store[nums[i]] = i;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i)
        {
            auto iter = store.find(target - nums[i]);
            if(iter != store.end() && (iter -> second) != i)
            {
                res.push_back(i);
                res.push_back(iter -> second);
                break;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

This solution takes 4ms in leetcode submission. Since I am looping through the same array twice, I was thinking to optimize my code by combining insert operation and map.find() into a single loop. Therefore I can check for a solution while inserting elements. Then I have the following solution:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) 
    {
        vector<int> res;
        map<int, int> store;

        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i)
        {
            auto iter = store.find(target - nums[i]);
            if(iter != store.end() && (iter -> second) != i)
            {
                res.push_back(i);
                res.push_back(iter -> second);
                break;
            }
            store[nums[i]] = i;
        }

        return res;
    }
};
```

However, the single loop version is much slower than two separate loops, which takes 12ms.

For further research, I made a test case where the input size is 100000001 and solution for this code will be [0, 100000001] (first index and last index). The following is my test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) 
{
    vector<int> res;
    map<int, int> store;

    for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i)
    {
        auto iter = store.find(target - nums[i]);
        if(iter != store.end() && (iter -> second) != i)
        {
            res.push_back(i);
            res.push_back(iter -> second);
            break;
        }
        store[nums[i]] = i;
    }

    return res;
}


vector<int> twoSum2(vector<int>& nums, int target) 
{
    vector<int> res;
    map<int, int> store;

    for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i)
    {
        store[nums[i]] = i;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i)
    {
        auto iter = store.find(target - nums[i]);
        if(iter != store.end() && (iter -> second) != i)
        {
            res.push_back(i);
            res.push_back(iter -> second);
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{

    std::vector<int> test1;
    test1.push_back(4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    {
        test1.push_back(3);
    }
    test1.push_back(6);

    std::clock_t start;
    double duration;

    start = std::clock();
    auto res1 = twoSum(test1, 10);
    duration = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout<<"single loop: "<< duration <<'\n';   
    cout << "result: " << res1[1] << ", " << res1[0] << endl;

    start = std::clock();
    res1 = twoSum2(test1, 10);
    duration = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout<<"double loops: "<< duration <<'\n';   
    cout << "result: " << res1[0] << ", " << res1[1] << endl;

}
```

I still get a similar result, which single loop version (7.9s) is slower than double loops version (3.0s):
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3t3B.png)

I don't really understand why a single loop combined version is slower than a double loops separated version? I think the single loop version should reduce some redundant looping. Is it because of the **STL map** implementation that it is better to do insertion and map.find() operation separately in two loops, rather than do insertion and map.find() alternately in one loop?

BTW I am working on a MAC OS and using Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.2).

Comment: Hmm... your two versions aren't equivalent, are they? The insertion `store[nums[i]] = i;` doesn't take place in every round in the single-loop version, because you break from the loop early?

Answer (score 4):

Let us see what actually happens in both scenarii.

In the two loops scenario, you do N insertions in the map, but then do only one find, because as the map is fully fed, you get the expected result on first iteration.

In the single loop scenario, you must wait for the last insertion to find the result. So you do N-1 insertions and N-1 find.

It is no surprise that it takes twice the time in your worst case test...

For randomized use cases, the two loop scenario will result in exactly N insertions, and statistically N/2 find. Best case N inserts 1 find, worst case N inserts N-1 finds.

In the single loop you start finding as soon as the map in not empty. The best case is 1 insert and 1 find (far better than two loops), and the worst case is N-1 inserts and N-1 finds. I know that it is easy to be misguided in probabilities, but I would expect statistically 3N/4 inserts and N/2 finds. So slightly better than the two loops scenario.

TL/DR: you get better results for the two loops scenario than for the single loop one, because your test case is the best for two loops and worst for single loop.